# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] using Pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm trying to install dependencies in django using `pipenv install`.
Then it responded error message like this in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Does file path in wrong or installation incomplete?

Python version - 3.10.4, pip version - pip 22.0.4 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pip (python 3.10)

```
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.1build1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/home/username/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.43ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/username/Documents/codes/storefront2/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.4) to create virtualenv...
⠏ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 184ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront2-Kl67gUFU, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/username/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.0.4, setuptools==62.1.0, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 56, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 222, in install
    do_install(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1964, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 552, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 485, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1012, in do_create_virtualenv
    project._environment = Environment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 70, in __init__
    self._base_paths = self.get_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 394, in get_paths
    c = subprocess_run(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/processes.py", line 75, in subprocess_run
    return subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront2-Kl67gUFU/bin/python'
```

Comment: Please run `sudo ls -l /home/username/.local/share/virtualenvs/storefront2-Kl67gUFU/bin/ | grep python` and see if there is a python executable

Comment: @sudden_appearance  there's no python  executable . "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 13):

```
pip uninstall -y setuptools
```

corrected above for me. See [FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] when installing pipenv from pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5075) for additional details

Comment: Fixed for me too! Thanks

Comment: I needed to run this as user and root/sudo.

Comment: this solution didn't work

Comment: I've got this error if I do that "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'"

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt remove pipenv
```